# How can I find in SQLite all the persons who share the same address as another person

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with clients and I'm trying to create a query which returns all the persons who have the same address as -say- John.

example

**Name**   **Address**

John   22 Acacia Avenue

Mary   22 Acacia Avenue

Leo    12 Nowhere street

Jake   22 Acacia Avenue

Cindy  43 Leeds street

Tom    78 Abbey Road

So, by looking for John, I'd get as a result

**Name**   **Address**

John   22 Acacia Avenue

Mary   22 Acacia Avenue

Jake   22 Acacia Avenue

I hope that's clear enough. I'm using SQLite 3.33 , thanks!

Comment: We could give you a query, but for posterity's sake it would be best if you add sample data to your question.

Comment: You are looking for the `join` keyword to look up in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thx guys, I'm  adding some sample data. Also, I couldn't quite work out how to do this with join as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a [subquery](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php).

```
select *
from people
where address = (
  select address
  from people
  where name = 'John'
)
```